# Shouldn't I be able to modify the main query by this filter?

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

**My Situation :**

I have a custom post type in my theme, called `article`.

My website has a dozen of categories, which i publish my posts in, and 1 **specific** category (named `BLOG`) just to publish `article` in it (has no `post` in it, only `article`).

My articles have different structure, so i can't show them in the same list that I show normal posts in archives. So, i decided to show articles only in `BLOG` category, and the normal posts in the rest of the categories.

This is the normal loop i have in my archives.php:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        the_title();
    }
}
```

And this goes in my theme's `functions.php`:

```
function archive_filtering($query){
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->have_posts()){
        $query->set('post_type', 'article' );
    }
}
```

**My Problem :**

I expect the above code to check to see if there is a post in this category, if there is no posts in it, then we might be in `BLOG` category. So, it should include the `article` post type in the query and then output it.

But it doesn't seem to work. Is this the proper approach? Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried re-saving the permalink structure? This looks like one of those times...

Comment: @Dan. Yes, unfortunately flushing the permalink and tweaking with `register_post_type` parameters doesn't work for me.

Comment: :(... Try setting the blog posts per page setting (in Settings->Reading) to `1` and then see if that works. If that works, then I think you need to specify the `posts_per_page` parameter in the `WP_Query args` for the custom post type part..

Comment: Nope... no success either. My blog has more than 10 posts and the post per page is set to 4.

Comment: 404s have nothing to do with the contents of template files, your archive template never gets loaded on a 404. WordPress determines if it's a 404 based on the results of the main query- the main query has no page 2.

Comment: @Milo I was wondering about that too, is there a way to replace my custom query with wp_query to somehow force it to load?

Comment: Ideally you should determine what sort of request it is before the main query runs, and do everything via the main query with `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: @Milo I changed my approach by your suggestion, now i'm stuck again. Would appreciate your attention.

Comment: I'm kind of confused about what you're trying to accomplish. Your current code doesn't work because the query hasn't run yet, you can't possibly know if there are any `found_posts`.

Comment: @Milo I just want to know if the query contains any default `post` type. If not, then change the post type to `article` and show the query results for `article` post type. Simple.

Comment: Again- the query already ran long before the template loaded, which means pre_get_posts already happened, you can't hook anything to it in the template for the main query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is because by the time archive.php runs, the `pre_get_posts` hook has already fired.

You can easily accomplish the task in your functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
  remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_pre_get_posts' );
  //* $query->have_posts() will always return false from this hook
  //* So get the posts with the query to check if they're empty
  $posts = get_posts( $query->query );
  if( empty( $posts ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'article' );
  }
}
```

And then your archive.php would be a simple loop:

```
if( have_posts() ) :
  while( have_posts() ) :
    the_post(); 
    the_title();
  endwhile;
endif;
```

This will run the query twice per request, which I wouldn't do, but offhand I can't see another way to do what you want.

Thanks @Milo. Edited because at the pre_get_posts hook, the query hasn't run yet. Duh.

Comment: Thanks. That was the first thing i tried, and it didn't work. That's why i'm confused.

Comment: You can't know if the query has posts before making the query.

Comment: @Milo So, How to achieve this? You mentioned that we can't alter the query this way, but didn't provide any solution (Please accept my apologies, i don't mean to be rude in ANY way.). If i use it in archive.php, the query has already been run. If i use it in functions.php, the query hasn't run yet. Seems like being stuck to me.

Comment: @JackJohansson I'm just not getting what "this" is. You want to paginate all the posts until there are no posts, then you want to show just articles on subsequent pages? It all just seems weird and unintuitive.

Comment: @Milo My original problem is that i have to have pagination on this. If you take a look at my original question (before first edit) you will see a custom loop that does 'this' for me, but can't have pagination on it. Now Wp-PageNavi offers pagination on custom queries, but i also need a basic pagination in case the customer doesn't want to install wp-pagenavi. If you give me 2 minutes of your time, i can explain it to you in chat.

Comment: NOW we're talking! Will search about any side effects, and let u know if there is any. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your scenario is that you can't know what changes need to be made to the query until after the query runs. Of course, after it runs, it's too late to make the changes!

You mentioned that you don't know what that single category all the articles are in might be. Well, the simplest way to solve this is to change that. You need some way to store that choice, so you can check if that's the category currently being requested, and make adjustments before the query is run.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_check_cat' );
function wpd_check_cat( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_category()
        && isset( $query->query_vars['category_name'] )
        && 'blog' == $query->query_vars['category_name'] ){
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'article' );
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Milo, but the other answer seems to work for now. Is there any reason not to use the answer provided by @Nathan?

Comment: I thought maybe it would result in an extra query, but I'm actually not sure now, since WordPress is usually pretty smart about caching queries.

Comment: I appreciate your interest in this question in the past 2 days, but i could use a `is_category('blog')` myself if i knew the category's name. Thank you both.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like WP grabs the taxonomy object first, so `$query->is_category('blog')` seems to work.